# Exclude a specific SQL column?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to `SELECT` random pages that haven't been liked or disliked by a certain user (user-id: `uid`) yet.

My table structure:

`OneNight_pages`: (id, title) `OneNight_pages_likes`: (id, page_id, uid, status)

And this is how I tried to get a random page:

```
SELECT 
p.id AS page_id, 
p.title, 
SUM(CASE WHEN l.page_id = p.id AND status = '1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS likes, 
SUM(CASE WHEN l.page_id = p.id AND status = '0' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS dislikes 

FROM OneNight_pages_likes l 
LEFT JOIN OneNight_pages p on l.page_id = p.id 
WHERE l.uid != '1' 
GROUP BY page_id 
ORDER BY rand() 
LIMIT 1
```

However this will still display pages that I already liked or disliked, because `WHERE l.uid != 1` doesn't affect to exclude a whole `l.page_id` (because there are other likers and dislikers for a particular page_id).

I guess I need to solve this with a subquery to receive a page id first or use some specific algorithm? I also thought of storing all liked and disliked pages as an array in a cookie or session, but I don't know if that's the right or efficient way to do it?

Comment: Can you provide sample data and expected results?  Having difficulty understanding...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
select p.*
from OneNight_pages p
where not exists (select 1
                  from OneNight_pages_likes l
                  where l.page_id = p.id and l.uid = '1' 
                 )
order by rand()
limit 1;
```

This selects a random page where user "1" has no rows in the likes table.

EDIT:

This variation on your query should do about the same thing:

```
SELECT p.id AS page_id, p.title, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN status = '1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS likes, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN status = '0' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS dislikes 
FROM OneNight_pages p LEFT JOIN
     OneNight_pages_likes l
     ON l.page_id = p.id
GROUP BY page_id
HAVING SUM(l.uid = 1) = 0
ORDER BY rand() 
LIMIT 1;
```

The previous version should have better performance.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. This seems to only show pages that haven't been liked at all now. So I only get pages without any likes or dislikes yet instead of only excluding one specific user?

Comment: @Vaia . . . This should exclude only likes by one particular user.

Comment: You're right, thanks! I used `l.uid != '1'` instead of `l.uid = '1'`

Comment: Sorry, to bother you again, but could you please update your answer to include also a count of likes and dislikes of the randomly selected page also? I used it with SUM in my question. When I include it in the subquery my result is empty.

Comment: So, it is not possible with the subquery to count likes and dislikes of the randomly selected page with `SUM()`? Because you also said it would have better performance, I'd like to prefer the sub-query-statement instead of the join.

Comment: @Vaia . . . A subquery in the `where` clause cannot return a column value.  It can only be used for filtering.

Comment: Okay, good to know! Do you think a second SQL-query (using your first sub-query-statement) afterwards just to get the likes and dislikes would be better performance-wise or just one SQL-query like your edit using LEFT JOIN?

Comment: @Vaia . . . You might as well use one query; but when it comes to performance, you can always try both ways and choose the one that works best.